# Is there anyway to press Control after pressing S then Z to stop the object from scaling down the face it encounters? This is usefull, how do I do it?

Tags: modeling, object-mode

[image]

like in the picture ,if the cube selected would stop on the floor when scaling in the z axis, how do I do this?

Is this control feature good to implement when transforming?

---

In Object Mode , that is, because Ctrl doesn't do nothing when transforming

Answer (score 1):

1. Set snap to face:

[image]

2. Move object on the ground by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

[image]

3. Using cursor tool, click anywhere on the ground, to set cursor here:
4. Set pivot point to 3D cursor

[image]

5. Scale in Z direction:

[image]

Comment: Moving pivot points is not necessary, you can snap while scaling.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the options for *Snapping* to *Snap To* > *Face*, and *Snap With* > *Closest* and then enable *Affect* > *Scale*, scaling the cube on the Z axis with <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> actually does exactly what you want.

[image: snapping options]

By the way: this snapping only works if you scale on a single axis. Let's say you wanted to snap the cube to the floor, but want to scale it even on all axes.

Here's what you can do: scale on Z axis to snap it onto the floor. Then go to the *Scale* values in the *Item* properties of the sidebar. You can see, the scale is still 1 on X and Y, but 5.463 on Z. To get the exact same value (and sometimes some decimals are clipped) on X and Y, just click and drag while holding the <kbd>LMB</kbd> to select all the values at once. If you start in the Z field and move the cursor upwards, the value from Z will automatically be copied into X and Y. Now simply press <kbd>Return</kbd> to apply the values. Since you didn't move the origin of the cube, the result would be as if you scaled on all axes at once and snapped to the floor.

[image: snapping evenly]